# Finding Taylor Series of $\frac{1}{(i+z)^2}$ centered at $z_0 = i$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor series of $$\frac{1}{(i+z)^2}$$ centered at $z_0 = i$.

Im thinking if I could find the Taylor series for $$\frac{1}{i+z}$$ I could use that $$\frac{d}{dz} \big(-\frac{1}{i+z} \big) = \frac{1}{(i+z)^2}$$ However Im struggling with finding the series of 1/(i+z) (I know I should use the geometric series), and also not sure how to make sure the series is centered at $z_0 = i$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Hint*. To find the Taylor series of $1/(i+z)$ use the known geometric series for $1/(1-w)$ in powers of $w$.

Comment: @GEdgar How do I ensure its centered at $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the Taylor series of $1/(i+z)$ in powers of $z-i$.  I could write $w = z-i$ and find the Taylor series of that in powers of $w$.

$$
\frac{1}{i+z} = \frac{1}{2i+w} 
$$

and recognize this as a geometric series with first term $1/(2i)$ and ratio $-w/(2i)$

$$
\frac{1}{2i+w} = 
\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{-w}{2i}}\right)
=\frac{1}{2i} + \frac{-w}{4} + \frac{w^2}{-8i} + \frac{-w^3}{-16} + \dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 1 {(i+z)^{2}}=-\frac 1 4 (1+(z-i)/2i)^{-2}$. Now use the expansion $(1+w)^{-2}=1+\frac {(-2)} {(1)} w+\frac {(-2)(-3)} {(1)(2)}w^{2}+\frac {(-2)(-3)(-4)} {(1)(2)(3)}w^{3}+\cdots$ for $|w| <1$.